# LaTeX - side-by-side subfigures?

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to create a float that spans two columns that has multiple side-by-side subfigures.  I've included the subcaption environment, and here's what I've got so far:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=black!100,mark=x] coordinates {
        (1, 4.89)
        (2, 6.74)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=black!100,mark=x] coordinates {
        (1, 21.9)
        (2, 15.6)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\label{Results2}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

However, this ends up giving me two subfigures one over the other.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: The blank line between your two `subfigure` environments is equivalent to a `\par` token. This creates a new paragraph, and the second `subfigure` gets placed underneath the first one. Try writing `\hfill` on that blank line.